# Python program gives internal error: _select is undefined

Tags: python

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

#Start creating a "pseudo-shell"... to give the users a good feeling.
print "Starting..."
import random #For generator
import time #For timer functions



#Always good to have whitespace

#Declare variables
gen_out = 0 #For generator output
user_num = 0 #Declare variable before input! It goes faster.
gen_floor = 0 #For declaring minimum... once again a prompt.
gen_ceiling = 0 #For maximum... another prompt.
time.sleep(4.75)#Make the pseudo-shell more lifelike.
print "Creating computer profile in memory...\nPlease wait."#More pseudo-shells...
time.sleep(12.9384587)#Here, we start the slowdown notification.
print "Done.\nI noticed your computer setup has not been approved to be fast. You may experience slowdowns in this program."#Make sure they think you made a bulky program... it'll come in handy with delays.
time.sleep(1.5493476)#Delay before integrity check
rnd_seed = ( random.randint(1,1000) * random.randint(1,1000) + 2463) #Integrity check... so we know they are not manipulating RAM.
rnd_seed_bak = rnd_seed #This makes 2 variables, one for generating, one for integrity check.
print rnd_seed + "\nPlease write down this number. You may need it if your PC hangs. You have 10 seconds to write it down."#Security check. Make 'em write!
time.sleep(10)#Stay true to your word.
print "Decompressing Linux."
time.sleep(4.8765)#Make them think they are booting a virtual machine. They'll have a reason to wait.
print "OK, booting the kernel.\n"
print "WARNING! Processes out of sync! Attempting fix...\n"#They need a stir...
time.sleep(2.98665)
print "OK, fixed!\n"
print "Initializing network daemon...   "#Make it real!!!
time.sleep(0.957531345543)
print "   [OK]\n"
print "Initializing Xorg shell...             [FAILED]\n"
print "WARNING!!!!! Xorg query came up as missing! Xorg not installed! When done, dropping to shell!\n"
time.sleep(0.567424567)
print "Boot taking too long! HURRY UP!\n"
print "CANNOT FIND \"VM VirtualBox HDD 1.vmdk\"!!! BACKUPS LOST!\n"
print "Continuing boot in silence mode...\n"
time.sleep(17.94627495638)
print "Done! Dropping to shell...\n\n\n"
time.sleep (0.9284657387)
print "Welcome to GenUx!\n\n\n"
print "Final touches being added...\n"
print "Boot complete! Sorry it took so long!\n"
print "How many numbers would you like generated...?\n"
user_num = hex(int(input("Input in Decimal:")))
gen_ceiling = hex(int(input("What is the ceiling in decimal?")))
gen_floor = hex(int(input("What is the floor in decimal?")))
```

Why does this give me "Internal Error: _select is undefined"? I have never had that error before... it confuses me! I have tried 3 different sites, several python versions... I can't find out why it does this!

Comment: `rnd_seed ` is an int so you are not going to be able to `+` to your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem in your code is trying to concat an int to  a string:

```
 rnd_seed + "\nPlease write down this number. You may need it if your PC hangs. You have 10 seconds to write it down.")  # Security check. Make 'em write!
```

You need to cast as a string:

```
str(rnd_seed) + ...
```

You should also be using `raw_input` not `input` for python2:

```
 gen_ceiling = hex(int(raw_input("What is the ceiling in decimal?")))
```

In python you don't have to declare variables so you can remove:

```
gen_out = 0 #For generator output
user_num = 0 #Declare variable before input! It goes faster.
gen_floor = 0 #For declaring minimum... once again a prompt.
```

and just assign the variables to the output from  `hex(int(raw_input...`

The error is a known [bug](https://github.com/replit/repl.it/issues/102) with repl, a far as your system python goes it must have somehow gotten compiled for a different platform.

Comment: which local ide are you using? It is either a python interpreter compiled for a different platform or a bug in the online repls

Comment: standard python 2 & 3, along with PyScripter

Comment: surely the code runs when you remove all the time.sleeps? Also what os?

Comment: Nope. It does the same thing

Comment: are you running it as a script or how exactly?

Comment: try `import time then  time.sleep(1)` in a python shell

Comment: "then" invalid syntax

Comment: on different lines and don't include then!

Comment: it's time module... That's strange

Comment: I do time.sleep(1) and same error. But If i gut them out of the program, it still errors

Comment: ok try the last three lines in your interpreter, the hex.... The errors I am certain are only related to time.sleep

Comment: WOW! ok... Now it works? It needed to remove time.sleep and fix the inputs! It works now. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I think your python interpreter has been somehow compiled for the wrong os, I would reinstall making sure to install the correct msi.